# 3.6V NiMH smart charger, microcontroller, auto switch over from DC in to battery

Tags: batteries, charger, nimh

I'm working on an agricultural pump monitor project using a microcontroller.  It needs to be able to operate ~1 hour after power failure, and signal same.

I'm hoping there are maybe single chip, or simple circuits using a smart chip, that will continually charge/monitor the 3.6V 700MAH battery, then to assume load on failure of the DC input power.  My searches are returning overnight, timed, and wall-plug discrete cell chargers.

Is Maxim 712 my only $$ choice?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why NiMH over LiPo?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79697/11606

Answer (score 1):

I have designed a simple circuit to charge NiCd batteries. The circuit continuously monitors the voltage of batteries. If the voltage drops, the batteries are being charged.
However, it is not exactly what you need, but it may give you some hints to design your own circuit. Here is the schematic:

[image]

More details can be found [here](http://newcircuits.com/circuit.php?id=chi002).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  Usually it's a good idea to post a schematic as an image.  This makes the question more valuable in the long run, because the URL of the link may change and the link may die.

Comment: You designed that? Are you the person responsible for newcircuits.com?

Comment: @Wolf: Yes, I designed the circuit, and I am the one who is responsible for the website newcircutis.com.